# A distributor of TVs determines that 1% of them are faulty. He sell them in bulk of 200 units and guarantees that 98% of the TVs won't be faulty.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-theorem, poisson-distribution

Find the probability that any particular 200 unit batch violates the guarantee

1. exactly, using a binomial distribution
2. using the Poisson approximation

Comment: Done. What's your question?

Comment: Sorry I've been trying to research how to write what I have so far using MathJax. So far I thought for the first one it would be $P(X \le 195)$ so then I did the $$\sum_{x=0}^{195} \binom{200}{x} * 0.99^x * 0.01^{200-x}$$ But I'm not so sure if this is right since I can't calculate it using my calculator without it throwing an error

Comment: @DuckDuckGone Use sums of logarithms in place of products of exponentials to solve the calculator problem.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm not sure how I'd do that. Sorry

Comment: $\log{a^bc^d}=b\log{a} + d\log{c}$.

Comment: For a numeric calculation of that sum, you might have better luck with WolframAlpha or (with a bit of care to handle the large numbers involved) a small program in C, Python etc. There are some numeric approximations and shortcuts you can use, but they basically wind up with the situation in the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch** The number of faulty TVs is $X\sim B(200,\,0.01)\approx\operatorname{Poisson}(2)$. The guarantee is honoured iff $X\le4$, with probability $\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{200}{k}0.01^k0.99^{200-k}\approx e^{-2}\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{2^k}{k!}$. Once either expression is calculated by summing just $5$ terms, subtraction from $1$ gives the probability of guarantee violation. By [my calculation](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/QuickwittedAshamedVoxels), the exact result $0.05175$ admits Poisson approximation $0.05265$.